# First steps in performance profiler: why is "Memory Usage" not an available tool and what's the problem with remote analysis?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, profiling, remote-debugging

As mentioned in the title, I'm having my first steps, using the performance profiler in Visual Studio on a C# application, and I have following questions:

- When starting up the performance profiler, the available tools contain both CPU Usage and Memory Usage (and many others), but when I change the target from the Startup Project to an already running process (which is in fact the startup project), then the Memory Usage is not an available tool anymore.
- I have recently started doing remote debugging (using `msvsmon.exe` on the remote PC), so I wanted to do performance profiling too on a remote process. Unfortunately changing the target to a running process only shows the processes, running on my local PC. Is there a way to change the target of the performance profiler to a process on remote computer?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When changing the target to an already running process, the tools available may change. This is normal. What kind of process?

Comment: It's a C# application.